# grep command always includes html tag with matching output

Tags: regex, bash, grep

This is a kind of bizarre problem..

I have a list of words between html tags, each separated by a line, with some whitespace on the left, like so:

```
    <td>word</td>
    <td>anotherWord</td>
    ...
```

I want to extract the words from the list and not the tags, so I use:

```
temp=$(printf "%s" "$temp" | egrep '[....]')
```

Just to clarify, "temp" is the input to be searched. (I am doing this in a bash script, and I stored the input in variable temp). The "..." is a list of characters, since the words I'm trying to extract only use certain characters.

Whenever the grep finds a match, it outputs the word along with the html tags on either side! This only happens with a match, because I tested this by having the regex parameter be gibberish, like '09680876' - it had no matches in the temp file, and grep outputted nothing.

I also tried to use a specific word that I knew was a match as the regex parameter, like so:

```
.... | egrep 'hanai')
```

where I knew 'hanai' was a definite match in the sample text. This resulted in grep outputting

```
<td>hanai</td>
```

I am completely stumped and haven't been able to find solutions online. Would appreciate someone pointing out the obvious mistake I'm making.

Comment: `egrep` is deprecated. Use `grep -E` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [a related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/can-grep-output-only-specified-groupings-that-match)  here and use of extended and perl patterns in grep (and egrep). You would have to use a regular expression which returns **only** the matched group (the text of tag) sth like this (not tested):

```
grep -oP '<[a-zA-Z]+> \K\[^<]+' test.txt
```

What the regex above does is return the text of the tag only, as matched group and reject any   open close tags

[grep extended patterns](http://www.real-world-systems.com/docs/grep.1.html)

Answer (score 2):

By default `grep` (and `egrep`) outputs the lines containing the matched pattern. If you only want the matched pattern use the `-o` flag.

From `man egrep`:

> ```
> -o, --only-matching
>        Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
>        with each such part on a separate output line.
> ```